# John the Ripper keeps on giving me errors: “Error: UTF-16 BOM seen in input file”

Tags: linux, passwords, kali-linux

I am learning to use Kali Linux, and I am just a beginner. I'm following a course in which is teaching me how to use “[John The Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/)” and I have followed the commands.

I have written:

```
locate rockyou.txt
```

This works perfectly okay but my problem is with the next command.
I write:

```
john --format=raw-md5 /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt.gz /root/Desktop/passw.txt
```

In the tutorial, the guy manages to crack the password, but for me it shows up with this error message:

```
Warning: invalid UTF-8 seen reading /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt.gz
Error: UTF-16 BOM seen in input file.
```

Why is this happening?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So is the file a .txt file or a .gz file?  What operating system was the file created on?

Comment: the "passw" file is .txt, I am on Kali Linux, but it's through VirtualBox on Windows 10

Comment: SO why isn’t the file extension in the second command a gz

Comment: Edit your question to include **ls -alh** for both of the directories in your question.  Do not submit this information as a comment.  Edit your question to include the instructions you are following.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, your passw.txt file might be the problem.

Try opening passw.txt in notepad++, look at the bottom right corner and if it says something like "UTF-16 BOM", go to the encoding menu near the top left and change it to UTF-8, save, and try running it again

Answer (score 0):

remove .gz from the second command. Run it like this:

```
john --format=raw-md5 /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt /root/Desktop/passw.txt
```

Comment: I've tried that, and it just comes up with this error:  stat: /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: When I have it saved to my desktop

Comment: **usr/share/wordlists/** would be the incorrect directory in that case if rockyou.txt is contained with the Desktop directory for the root user.

Comment: ok, run the command 'gunzip /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt.gz' then try my solution again. According to the error in your post, /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt.gz exists it's just compressed.

Comment: *A .gz file would indeed have a UTF-16 BOM character.*

Comment: @Ramhound Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the wordlist for that course. Do this, it'll work

```
john --format=raw-md5 /root/Desktop/passw.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

extract the gzip using **gunzip**

```
gunzip /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt.gz
```

then use the extracted text file (rockyou.txt) to crack the hash

```
john --format=Raw-MD5 -w=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt /root/Desktop/passw.txt
```